# The set of non-null ideals of a ring has a monoid structure with the product of the ideals. If the ring is a PID then the monoid is cancellative.

Tags: abstract-algebra

I know that a monoid is an algebraic structure with a single associative binary operation and an identity element.

On the first part, I have done a simple proof about this issue but I don't know how I can prove this result in a more rigorous way. How would you try it?

On the other hand, I don't know how I can prove that if a commutative ring is a principal ideal domain then the monoid satisfies the cancellation property.

I want to clarify that I suppose that the ring in question is **commutative**.

Comment: The first sentence of your title is false, if “non-null” means nonzero. It can happen that the product of two nonzero ideals is zero.

Comment: I am not sure what you claim. Could you give me a counterexample? I understand de product of two ideals as the ideal generated by all products of the form $ab$ with $a$ in $A$ and $b$ in $B$, where $A$ and $B$ are ideals of a ring $R$.

Comment: Also it is good to know the cancellation fails in some integral domains for example $R= \Bbb{Z}[2i]$ then $(2) (2,2i) = (2i) (2,2i)$ while $(2) \ne (2i)$. Dedekind domain means an integral domain where all non-zero ideal $I$ is invertible : there exists $J$ such that $IJ = (a)$ with $a \ne 0$. In a unital non-commutative ring the two-sided ideals form a monoid but not the right ideals (because $(1)$ is identity only on the right)

Comment: @JMaths21: consider the ring $\mathbb{Z}/4$ and the ideal $I = (2)$. We have $I^2 = (0)$ is the zero ideal. This will happen more generally in any ring with zero divisors, for example nilpotents. So it's not true that the set of *nonzero* ideals has a monoid structure, unless you assume e.g. that $R$ is an integral domain.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $(a)(b) = (a)(c)$. Then $ab$ and $ac$ are associates, i.e. $ab = uac$ for a unit $u$. Since the underlying ring is a domain, we can cancel $a$ and get the desired result.